# Rails Heroku custom domain with Facebook login - Given URL is not allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, facebook-oauth

I'm having trouble getting Heroku custom domain to play well with the Facebook oauth login

I am getting the error

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

which is examined in various threads including the Facebook one
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=542958419109491

So far, my setup is this
the root
http://domain.com is redirect to to http://www.domain.com

The cnames have been changed for www.domain.com so it is an alias for my heroku app. Shows up fine.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains There does say
"Zone apex domains (aka “naked”, “bare” or “root” domains), e.g., example.com, using conventional DNS A-records are not supported on Heroku. However, there are alternative configurations that allow for root domains while still being resilient in a dynamic runtime environment."

but I don't know how this effects FB login

When I click the facebook login, it'll throw that error. I've tried various setups in my app settings including with and without the www

Right now, I've left it as

```
App domain: domain.com 
Site URL: http://domain.com
Mobile site URL: http://domain.com
Embedded browser OAuth Login is enabled
```

(I've tried www for all the options above, but maybe there is a combination I haven't tried. I'm really just doing it randomly not knowing why one would work over another)

If I can't resolve this, I might try opening an issue on Facebook tomorrow.

Comment: All that matters is the domain name that is used in the browser when the user is visiting your app.

Comment: okay.. they're visiting from www.domain.com so why doesn't it work when i change the site url to `http://www.domain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This final combination seemed to work as my site is coming from www.domain.com

```
App domain: domain.com 
Site URL: http://www.domain.com
Mobile site URL: http://www.domain.com
Embedded browser OAuth Login is enabled
```

Redirect uri in Advanced setting also added http://www.domain.com